# React. Подключение шрифтов. module.css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html5, модули

Не могу подключить шрифт в React приложение. Для стилизации использую module.css. Куда только не подключал и в index.css (не module.css) и отдельным файлом stylesheet.css.

[image]

Comment: покажите примеры кода, как именно вы пытались подключать

Comment: Я решил, этот вопрос. Подключил в Index.html через link. Особо не заморачиваясь. ))